# Using Ninject to Create Typed Repository Sets

Tags: repository, ninject, strong-typing

I want to avoid ctors that take a large number of repository interfaces.

Instead, I want to have a single ctor parameter: a typed repository set.

By typed, I mean a class with a bunch of properties for each repository that the enclosing class uses. Something like this:

```
public sealed class MyRepositorySet
{
    public IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

    public IOtherRepository OtherRepository { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use Ninject to automatically create such a repository set, populate each of the properties by creating an instance of each repository, and then create the dependent class with the initialized repository set.

I know this can be done, but I can't find an example. I don't think I know what a typed repository set is properly called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actual answered my own question. Ninject had everything I needed to do the job, just not out-of-the-box. After calling Bind() an instance of IBindingToSyntax is returned. It has a method called WithPropertyValue. This method takes a value or a callback. The callback has an instance of Ninject.Activation.IContext, which has a IKernel, which finally has the Get method. So... I can look at the type of the property named in WithPropertyValue, grab the property, determine the type and then have the callback Get an instance for the property type. Phew.

Here is an extension class I wrote to help in populating my typed repository sets:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Activation;
using Ninject.Planning.Targets;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace NinjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides extension methods for the BindingWithSyntax class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class BindingWithSyntaxExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the specified property should be injected with the bound type of the property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the property.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> WithPropertyValue<TBinding>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance, string name)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(TBinding).GetProperty(name);
            if (propertyInfo == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("There was not a public property with the given name.", "name");
            }
            Func<IContext, object> callback = context => context.Kernel.Get(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            return instance.WithPropertyValue(name, callback);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the specified property should be injected with the bound type of the property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyGetter">An expression yielding the property to set the value to.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> WithPropertyValue<TBinding, T>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance, Expression<Func<TBinding, T>> propertyGetter)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            if (propertyGetter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyGetter");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = getPropertyInfo(typeof(TBinding), propertyGetter);
            Func<IContext, object> callback = context => context.Kernel.Get<T>();
            return instance.WithPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, callback);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the specified property should be injected with the given value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyGetter">An expression yielding the property to set the value to.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value to set the property to.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> WithPropertyValue<TBinding, T>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance, Expression<Func<TBinding, T>> propertyGetter, T value)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            if (propertyGetter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyGetter");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = getPropertyInfo(typeof(TBinding), propertyGetter);
            return instance.WithPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the specified property should be injected with the value returned by the callback.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyGetter">An expression yielding the property to set the value to.</param>
        /// <param name="callback">A function to call to retrieve the value to set the property to.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> WithPropertyValue<TBinding, T>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance, Expression<Func<TBinding, T>> propertyGetter, Func<IContext, T> callback)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            if (propertyGetter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyGetter");
            }
            if (callback == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = getPropertyInfo(typeof(TBinding), propertyGetter);
            Func<IContext, object> baseCallback = context => callback(context);
            return instance.WithPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, baseCallback);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates that the specified property should be injected with the value returned by the callback.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <param name="propertyGetter">An expression yielding the property to set the value to.</param>
        /// <param name="callback">A function to call to retrieve the value to set the property to.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> WithPropertyValue<TBinding, T>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance, Expression<Func<TBinding, T>> propertyGetter, Func<IContext, ITarget, T> callback)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            if (propertyGetter == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyGetter");
            }
            if (callback == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = getPropertyInfo(typeof(TBinding), propertyGetter);
            Func<IContext, ITarget, object> baseCallback = (context, target) => callback(context, target);
            return instance.WithPropertyValue(propertyInfo.Name, baseCallback);
        }

        private static PropertyInfo getPropertyInfo<T>(Type bindingType, Expression<T> expression)
        {
            if (expression.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The expression did access a property.", "propertyGetter");
            }
            MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
            if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType != MemberTypes.Property)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The expression did not access a property.", "propertyGetter");
            }
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
            if (!propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(bindingType))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The expression did not access a property in the specified type.", "propertyGetter");
            }
            return propertyInfo;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Injects every property with the bound type of the property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TBinding">The type of the object to set the property for.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="instance">Used to add additional information to a binding.</param>
        /// <returns>The instance that was passed in.</returns>
        public static IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> SetAllProperties<TBinding>(this IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> instance)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
            }
            IBindingWithSyntax<TBinding> result = instance;
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(TBinding).GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyInfo local = property;
                result = result.WithPropertyValue(local.Name, context => context.Kernel.Get(local.PropertyType));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to configure a typed repository set like this:

```
Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>();
Bind<MyRespositorySet>().ToSelf()
                        .WithPropertyValue(set => set.MyRepository);
```

I also took some time to create a Module builder to save me from needing to create a separate Module class for each unit test I write. But that is a pretty big chunk of code, so I'll leave it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are completely on the wrong track. Instead of implementing a workaround to reduce the number of constructor arguments you should better fix your real problem which is that your class most likely does not follow the single responsibility principle. In most cases where a class needs a lot of dependencies the single responsibility principle is violated.

Comment: Think of an ASP.NET MVC controller. It performs many tasks depending on the different actions it supports. In order to perform those actions, it requires access to various database tables, configuration settings, etc. In order to break the dependencies, I am using repositories. A single responsibility does not imply a single dependency.

Comment: Controllers are no exceptions. If you need different repositories for different actions then those actions probably shouldn't be in the same controller. And/Or the work should be delegated to services instead of doing everything in the controllers.

Comment: I already gave you an example: configuration settings and database tables. At some point in the code, those two pieces of information need to become available so that dependent code can access them. In some way or another, that information needs to combined. Whatever combines that data MUST be aware of both of them. I am really looking for an answer to my original post, rather than a theory-based debate. Have a little faith in my development experience, please.

Comment: Sorry I'm not giving solutions to ploblems that are against my own understanding of proper software architecture. Injecting a set of something instead of the required dependencies does not improve the implementation in any way. The oposite is the case in my opinion. It obfuscases what dependencies are required. Regarding your problem I would never inject a repository for configuration but rather the configuration values themselves. SRP => getting the config is a responsibility. Operating on a lot of tables is most likely against SRP too. SRP in an easy rule that is difficult to apply.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you initialize a type with properties coming from various sources without the factory type needing to be aware of multiple sources as well. It seems like a recursive problem. I would also be interested in seeing how you handle business logic in any situation where operations involve updating multiple database tables at the same time. For instance, our system tracks metrics whenever users connect to various services, such as Google Analytics. Whether or not to track metrics depends on the type of the service and whether a metric has already been recorded.

Comment: The key point is separation of concerns. One class - one responsibility. This isn't always easy but worth to find a solution for instead of searching workarounds for large constructors. I can't give you a detailed solution as I don't know your application. But taking your example. tracking shouldn't be a responsibility of the controller. Since tracking is a cross cutting concern this might better be implemented using a (configurable) filter instead.

Comment: @Travis Parks at the risk of sounding like a broken record... Highly recommend manning.com/seemann for getting to understand these architectural concerns based on both principles, patterns and well worked examples (and http://www.amazon.com/Agile-Principles-Patterns-Practices-C/dp/0131857258/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1323682418&sr=8-2 does the same thing without being about DI containers)